# Persistent login curl magento and get data

Tags: php, magento, curl

i use this for loggin to magento with curl

```
session_start();

$string = "login[username]=".urlencode("me@mymagentodomain.co.uk")."&login[password]=".urlencode("password");

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.mymagentodomain.co.uk/customer/account/loginPost');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, session_name().'='.session_id());
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $string);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);

$output = (string) curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

preg_match('/frontend=(.+); expires=/i', $output, $matches);
$temp = $matches[0];
$sid = str_replace(array("frontend=","; expires="), "", $temp);
```

1) I want to know how to keep the session logged with curl

2) How to get data from other page with logged session.

3) Thx in advance !

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
session_start(); 
$cookie = 'PHPSESSID=' . $_COOKIE['PHPSESSID'];

session_write_close(); 

$ch = curl_init('url_here');
...
...
...
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, $cookie);
...
... 
curl_exec($ch); 
curl_close($ch);
```

http://php.net/session_write_close

Comment: Just i try to connect to a magento website and get some information in account page.